# attach derby database into jar file

Tags: netbeans-7, javadb

I am midway through a database application(SWING). I am using Java DB and NetBeans 7.1.2. Within the IDE, the app runs good, provided I initially connect the database manually in the 'services' window. Also, I have added the derby.jar and derbyclient.jar files to the libraries. But when running the app from the "dist" folder, it fails to connect to the database. I want to know whether i can attach the db within the jar file so that i can run the app from outside the IDE. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

- Start `java DB` outside the netbeans or
- If you use Derby, go with `Embedded mode`. Such a way you can run your application without separate db server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, can you please make it clear.? I didnt get your FIRST point. Also, I am using the database in the Embedded Mode.

Comment: @user1538162 If you use java DB in network, you need separate Java DB Server. Otherwise it is not required. my first point is for Network db connection. So when you use Embedded mode, U need to specify class path of your `derby.jar` to your jar file.

Comment: I did that too. But no +ve result.